# Parsing Serial communication in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application that requires I send a string of 4-10 ASCII character to an RS422 Uart serial receiver. The problem is that the Uart buffer can only receive 2bytes max ever 10ms or so. How do I parse out the data and send it in chunks without timing out on the other side.

Normal serial.write() method overflows the buffer and I get an error response from the device every time I send anything. The device specified a baudrate of 19200 but also say the data i write needs to be spaced out 2 bytes at a time. There is no parity, handshake or flow control support for the device.

Essentially I want to do something like this:

```
private void sendData(string text)
   {
      string  textnew = text +(char)13;

      byte[] r_bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textnew);

       if (SeriialComms.IsOpen)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i > (textnew.Length/2); i = i + 2)
            {
                byte[] bytesToSend = { r_bytes[i], r_bytes[i+1] };
                SerialComms.Write(bytesToSend, 0, 2);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }
   }
```

is this possible and is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: What specific device are you communicating with, does it support any kind of flow control? Also I don't know if "parse" is really the correct word to use, but I don't know what the correct word would be.

Comment: Can't you just use the [SerialPort.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143551(v=vs.110).aspx) method?

Comment: If you want non-blocking thread way I suggest using Reactive Extensions. http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/13_TimeShiftedSequences.html

Comment: Well, that's a pretty miserable device to put it mildly.  You should aggressively pursue the option to lower the baudrate.  If that's truly impossible then you'll have to pinvoke `timeBeginPeriod(10)` to make the sleep accurate.  And send only *one* byte at a time before sleeping again.